# How to reorder if there are numbers in the filename using javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote an app where I allow users to upload files.

I am unable to force how the users choose their filenames. However, they are likely to use

- page1, page2, page3, etc
- pp1, pp2, pp3, etc
- p1, p2, p3, etc

because of this, I need to reorder using javascript. Right now, I have the issue of getting this order.

- page1, page10, page11, page12, page2, page20, page21, etc.

How do I get the order I want, regardless how the users put in the filename at the start of the filenames?

Thank you.

Comment: You can change file names at the file uploading stage   with starting zero like page1 -> page01

Comment: How would I do that? I need a function to separate the text and the number yes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example. This will format 4 digit number to file name. You can change it by changing **4** to whatever you want

```
<?php
$str = 'page2';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);

$format_number= str_pad($matches[0][0], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);


echo $filename=str_replace($matches[0][0], $format_number, $str);

?>
```